# Jquery removeClass doesn't remove associated styles

Tags: jquery

I have a div with some class and I add some css using Jquery

```
$('.myClass').css("position","absolute");
```

After few steps I remove the class `myClass`, using

```
$('.myDiv').removeClass('myClass');
```

But the style `position:absolute` is not removing.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Because those 2 are not associated... teh class is used as a selector to find the elements after that whatever you do is irrespective of the class

Comment: @ajai $('.myClass').css("position","absolute"); means you are directly injecting styles to the div not to the class

Comment: How can I attach styles to that class? Because I want to remove those styles after few steps.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `removeAttr( 'style' )` .

Which is the jquery function to remove the element.style.

Comment: I think this is a bad approach because he may remove other inline styles that were originally in the HTML

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you did

```
$('.myClass').css("position","absolute");
```

it added the style **inline**

Calling `addClass` will add a **named** style from a style-sheet.

Calling `css` will apply the styles *inline* to the element.

To remove the style you applied with `css`, simply do

```
$('.myClass').css("position","");
```

Comment: if he has only one style position. $('.myClass').css("position",""); is simple , else it will be lengthy coding. Best to use jquerys default function of remove attr : removeAttr()

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` is not attached to the class

When we remove the class, it removes the styling defined with it like defining style in CSS files

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using your current code the better way is create a new css class like this

```
.position-absolute{

 position:absolute;
}
```

the add this class to the div

```
$('.myDiv').addClass('position-absolute');
```

and remove the class after use

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing
$('.myClass').css("position","absolute");

That means you are selecting a div having Class named "myClass" and adding that style to that particular div.

But when you are writing 
$('.myDiv').removeClass('myClass');

That means you are selecting a div having Class named "myDiv" and removing that class named "myClass". But that class does not include that style("position","absolute"), so it will not be removed.